# Mixing defaultdict (dict and int) to get nested default dictionary with sum of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I have 2 example lists and what I want to achieve is to obtain a *nested* default dictionary with the sum of the values.

The following code works nice:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
dd = defaultdict(int)

for i in l1:
    for ii in l2:
        dd[i] += ii
```

but what I'm trying to do is to create a default key in the `d` dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
dd = defaultdict(int)

for i in l1:
    for ii in l2:
        dd[i]['mykey'] += ii
```

and this throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Basically what I'm not able to understand is if there is the chance to mix `defaultdict(dict)` and `defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The defaultdict data structure receives a function that will supply the default value, so if you want to create a `defautdict(int)` as default value provide a function that does that, for example `lambda : defaultdict(int)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

dd = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

for i in l1:

    for ii in l2:
        dd[i]['mykey'] += ii


pprint(dd)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7efc74d78f28>,
            {1: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
             2: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
             3: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
             4: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26})})
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you want a default dict of a default dict of integer:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

after running your code:

```
>>> dd
{1: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
 2: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
 3: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26}),
 4: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'mykey': 26})}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I should accept  Daniel Mesejo answer just because he replied some seconds before you. Thanks anyway!

Comment: no he didn't. I was ahead by 20 seconds (hover on "answered x hours ago" to see the exact date), but whoever needs the rep :)