# Creating defaultdict with Counter vs int vs lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I am writing a code where I have to keep a count of various words in nested dict.

```
nestedCounts = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
for j, tagList in enumerate(sequences_A):
    for a, b in zip(sequences_A[j], sequences_B[j]):
        nestedCounts[a][b] += 1
```

When I wrote `nestedCounts=defaultdict(int)` , it showed an TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

When I changed it to `nestedCounts=defaultdict(Counter)` , it ran fine.

When I changed it to `nestedCounts=defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))` , it was also running fine.

Then in Second case I needed another dict(not nested)

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(sequences)):
    for j in sequences[i]:
        counts[j] += 1
```

When I was wrote `counts=defaultdict(int)` , it ran fine.

When I changed it to `counts=defaultdict(Counter)` , it showed AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'.

When I changed it to `counts=defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))` , it showed TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'collections.defaultdict' and 'int'.

Can anyone explain what is happening & in which case we should use Counter or int or lambda. What I understood is when we create defaultdict(int) basically it will provide a default value to 0. But I did not understand why I got error in case of using Counter.

P.S. - I referred to this link but still not understood.
[mixing defaultdict (dict and int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894698/mixing-defaultdict-dict-and-int)

Comment: You need to provide the code you're having the problem with - i.e. the code that's not working. See [mre].

Comment: Showing us the one line where you tried multiple variants, is not helpful. We can't interpret that line without its context. Please show the whole function.

Comment: Actually on second thought I think I see what you're confused about. I'll post an answer, but a MRE would still help.

Comment: Have added the code of both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict(int)` is practically equivalent to `Counter` here, so I'm  going to ignore `defaultdict(int)` to save space.

`Counter` makes a flat data structure like `{foo: 0}`, which doesn't work with your nested dict.

`defaultdict(Counter)` makes a nested data structure like `{foo: {bar: 0}}`, which doesn't work with your flat dict.

Comment: What about defaultdict(Counter). Why doesnt it work in both the cases?

Comment: @Pratik I just edited to change which one I'm focusing on, sorry for any confusion. But it's like I said, `defaultdict(int)` is practically equivalent to `Counter` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. May i know the why does the counter work like that. Any documentation link will be really helpful.

Comment: @Pratik official documentation: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: I have gone through this documentation. I was facing difficulty in understanding why this counter when used with defaultdict will result in nested dict.

Comment: I got that for int it will be simple dict and for lambda it will be nested dict. Can you please explain the rationale behind that

Comment: @Pratik Oh then you want to read the documentation for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), especially this part: *"`__missing__(key)` ... If `default_factory` is not `None`, it is called without arguments to provide a default value for the given `key`, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the `key`, and returned."*